# I am trying to translate an existing Makefile to a CMakeLists.txt but the compiled project results in a Segfault

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, julia

I am trying to build a project using CMake instead of a given Makefile. I need to do this since I want to wrap the C++ Code via Julias CxxWrap, which also has a build recipe using CMake. However I am not sure how to get all the compiler flags and so on translated properly.

The Makefile is the following:

```
     ================= Libraries and Includes ====================================

INOUT_INCLUDE_DIR = ./InOut/include
STRUCT_INCLUDE_DIR = ./DataStruct/include
DELCX_INCLUDE_DIR = ./Delcx/include
ALFCX_INCLUDE_DIR = ./Alphacx/include
VOLUMES_INCLUDE_DIR = ./Volumes/include

INCLUDE_DIRS = -I$(INC_DIR) -I$(INOUT_INCLUDE_DIR) -I$(STRUCT_INCLUDE_DIR)\
        -I$(DELCX_INCLUDE_DIR) -I$(ALFCX_INCLUDE_DIR) -I$(VOLUMES_INCLUDE_DIR)
GMP_LIB_DIR =
LIB_DIRS =

GMP_LIBS = -lgmp
LIBS = $(GMP_LIBS) -lstdc++

# ================= Project Directories ====================================

INC_DIR = ./project/include
SRC_DIR = ./project/src
OBJ_DIR = ./project/src
BIN_DIR = ./bin

# ================= Project Name ===========================================

EXT=
NAME=AlphaMol
NAMEOBJ=$(OBJ_DIR)/$(NAME).o
NAMEBIN=$(BIN_DIR)/$(NAME)$(EXT)

# ================= Compilers and Flags ====================================

CPP         := g++
CPPFLAGS    := -c -O3 -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wuninitialized -ansi -Werror -Wunused -std=c++11

LOAD_LIB_PATH =

LD_FLAGS = -O3

# ================= Pattern rules ==========================================

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) $< -o $@

# ================= Compile source code ====================================

OBJECTS = \
$(NAMEOBJ)

# ================= Generate Executable ====================================

$(NAMEBIN) : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CPP) -o $(NAMEBIN) $(LD_FLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LIB_DIRS) $(LIBS) $(LOAD_LIB_PATH)

all: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CPP) -o $(NAMEBIN) $(LD_FLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LIB_DIRS) $(LIBS) $(LOAD_LIB_PATH)

clean:
    touch $(OBJ_DIR)/junk.o; rm -f $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o $(NAMEBIN)

$(OBJECTS):
```

My attempt at doing "the same thing but including CxxWrap via CMake looks like this:

```
    project(AlphaMol)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH 1)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -gdwarf-3")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG} -gdwarf-3")

#JLCXX
find_package(JlCxx)
get_target_property(JlCxx_location JlCxx::cxxwrap_julia LOCATION)
get_filename_component(JlCxx_location ${JlCxx_location} DIRECTORY)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib;${JlCxx_location}")

message(STATUS "Found JlCxx at ${JlCxx_location}")

add_library(AlphaMol SHARED AlphaMol.cpp)

target_link_libraries(AlphaMol JlCxx::cxxwrap_julia)

#GMP
set(GMP_PREFIX "" CACHE PATH "path ")

find_path(GMP_INCLUDE_DIR gmp.h gmpxx.h
        PATHS ${GMP_PREFIX}/include /usr/include /usr/local/include )

find_library(GMP_LIBRARY NAMES gmp libgmp
        PATHS ${GMP_PREFIX}/lib /usr/lib /usr/local/lib)

if(GMP_INCLUDE_DIR AND GMP_LIBRARY)
    get_filename_component(GMP_LIBRARY_DIR ${GMP_LIBRARY} PATH)
    set(GMP_FOUND TRUE)
endif()

if(GMP_FOUND)
    if(NOT GMP_FIND_QUIETLY)
        MESSAGE(STATUS "Found GMP: ${GMP_LIBRARY}")
    endif()
elseif(GMP_FOUND)
    if(GMP_FIND_REQUIRED)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find GMP")
    endif()
endif()

target_link_libraries(AlphaMol ${GMP_LIBRARY})

target_include_directories(AlphaMol PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:../include>
        )

target_include_directories(AlphaMol PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Alphacx/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:/../../Alphacx/include>
        )

target_include_directories(AlphaMol PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../DataStruct/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:/../../DataStruct/include>
        )

target_include_directories(AlphaMol PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Delcx/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:/../../Delcx/include>
        )

target_include_directories(AlphaMol PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../InOut/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:/../../InOut/include>
        )

target_include_directories(AlphaMol PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Volumes/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:/../../Volumes/include>
        )

install(TARGETS
        AlphaMol
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
        RUNTIME DESTINATION lib)
```

I understand that this is still a good way from being finished, but I am a proper C++ noob and any help would be greatly appreciated!

The c++ project is available on github: [https://github.com/pkoehl/AlphaMol]
Thanks in advance

Vlad

Comment: First of all do a verbose build using CMake, take a look at all the commands invoked by the build-system created by CMake. Look at flags and options. How do they differ from the commands used by Make in your `Makefile`?

Comment: Also, if different ways of building your application results in crashes, then you probably have *undefined behavior* in your code. The root-cause is very likely in your source, and unrelated to the build system.

Comment: One thing I'd check is where cmake is putting its target binaries vs where make is. CxxWrap could be looking in the wrong place when it's trying to resolve symbols.

Comment: The "need" described is a nice-to-have. Don't get me wrong, the goal is what I'd call "worthy,"  but you can also. duct tape your project together with a script that invokes cmake to build your dependency and then calls the project-wide file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following CMake File which gets the job done. Note that I am now building a Shared library. Furthermore, I actually did not specify any compiler flags. In the end it was just a matter of linking the correct libraries.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)
project(alphamol)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# Try to find the GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library (GMP)
find_path(GMP_INCLUDE_DIR gmp.h
    PATHS /usr/include /usr/local/include )

find_library(GMP_LIBRARY NAMES gmp
    PATHS /usr/lib /usr/local/lib)

if(GMP_INCLUDE_DIR AND GMP_LIBRARY)
    get_filename_component(GMP_LIBRARY_DIR ${GMP_LIBRARY} PATH)
    set(GMP_FOUND TRUE)
endif()

if(GMP_FOUND)
   if(NOT GMP_FIND_QUIETLY)
      MESSAGE(STATUS "Found GMP: ${GMP_LIBRARY}")
   endif()
elseif(GMP_FOUND)
   if(GMP_FIND_REQUIRED)
      message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find GMP")
   endif()
endif()

# Include JLCxx
find_package(JlCxx)
get_target_property(JlCxx_location JlCxx::cxxwrap_julia LOCATION)
get_filename_component(JlCxx_location ${JlCxx_location} DIRECTORY)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib;${JlCxx_location}")

message(STATUS "Found JlCxx at ${JlCxx_location}")

# AlphaMol includes
list(APPEND ALPHAMOL_INCLUDE_DIRS "DataStruct/include")
list(APPEND ALPHAMOL_INCLUDE_DIRS "Delcx/include")
list(APPEND ALPHAMOL_INCLUDE_DIRS "Alphacx/include")
list(APPEND ALPHAMOL_INCLUDE_DIRS "InOut/include")
list(APPEND ALPHAMOL_INCLUDE_DIRS "Volumes/include")
list(APPEND ALPHAMOL_INCLUDE_DIRS "project/include")


# build app
file(GLOB ALPHAMOL_SOURCE "project/src/*.cpp")
include_directories(${ALPHAMOL_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GMP_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_library(AlphaMol SHARED ${ALPHAMOL_SOURCE})
target_link_libraries(AlphaMol gmp JlCxx::cxxwrap_julia)
```